# How can I optimize @property method by prefetching or caching an "unrelated" table

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-orm

I have three model objects, two of which directly relate to each other.

```
class Child(models.Model):
    date_of_birth = models.DateField()
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=Gender.choices)

    @property
    def age(self):
        today = date.today()
        return age_on_date(date_calculating_on=today, date_of_birth=self.date_of_birth)
```

```
class ChildBmiCheck(models.Model):

    child = models.ForeignKey(Child, models.PROTECT, related_name="bmi_checks")
    height_in_meters = models.DecimalField(max_digits=40, decimal_places=10, null=True)
    weight_in_kgs = models.DecimalField(max_digits=40, decimal_places=10, null=True)
    child_was_present = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    @property
    def zscore(self):
        if self.child_was_present is True:
            age = self.child.age * 12  # in months
            gender = self.child.gender

            # TODO this is slow because for every child bmi check we hit the DB
            #  |
            #  V
            matching_data = ReferenceZscoreData.objects.filter(sex=gender).get(age=age)

            return self.calculate_z_score(matching_data)
        else:
            return None
```

And one that is used under the comment in the @property method above, which is not directly related through a foreign key relationship.

```
class ReferenceZscoreData(models.Model):
    sex = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=Sex.choices, db_index=True)
    age = models.IntegerField(db_index=True)


    property1ForZscore = models.FloatField()
    property2ForZscore = models.FloatField()
    property3ForZscore = models.FloatField()
```

When I fetch Child BMI checks, I see that the DB is queried for the relavent ReferenceZscoreData every time this method is called. This makes the HTTP fetch in Django Rest Framework really slow. However, ReferenceZscoreData only changes once a year, so there is no reason to go to the database so often.

I tried adding this table to prefetch_related, but it isn't related through any ForeignKey relationship.

```
class ChildBmiCheckViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = ChildBmiCheck.objects.prefetch_related(
        'child'
        # There is no reference_z_score_data because this is related through an @property only!
    ).all()
    serializer_class = ChildBmiCheckSerializer
    permission_classes = [permissions.AllowAny]
```

How can I prefetch or cache this value to optimize it?

Comment: You should probably consider calculating it and saving the z_score value on the ChildBmiCheck model as a field. And whenever there is a change in your ReferenceZscoreData, you can run a script to update it for all ChildBmiCheck instances

Comment: @ybl I'm considering that, but I worry that it might not stay in sync, and is more bug prone. I'm also looking into annotate, but its harder to write the formula with annotate's kinda-python-kinda-sql keywords. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/db/aggregation/#generating-aggregates-for-each-item-in-a-queryset

Comment: If you already have celery in the system, it is easy to ensure eventual consistency with a daily task. Honestly, I cannot think of a reason for it to be bug-prone. From my understanding, there is nothing much you can do if you don't want to precompute and save data which depends on varied input(the query). A middle ground is to use a caching framework to make subsequent API calls faster.

Comment: As for annotate, it would help to minimize the number of queries but might lead to an arguably slower query, because of joins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to fetch the data in one db hit.

But before proceeding, I would suggest you add a `DateTimeField` or an `IntegerField` (representing age) to `ChildBmiCheck`, since one child can have multiple height and weight records, each links to a specific timestamp.

Although following methods still uses `Child.date_of_birth` attribute.

**Method 1. Annotating Subquery**

```
from django.db.models import Func, OuterRef, Subquery
from django.db.models.functions import Floor, Extract

subquery_ref = ReferenceZscoreData.objects.filter(age=OuterRef('age'), sex=OuterRef('child__gender'))

queryset = ChildBmiCheck.objects.annotate(
    # Extract(interval, 'epoch') returns total number of seconds
    # then divide by 3600, 24, 30 returns hours, days, months respectively
    age = Floor(Extract(Func('child__date_of_birth', function='AGE'), 'epoch') / 3600 / 24 / 30)
).annotate(
    prop1 = Subquery(subquery_ref.values('property1ForZscore')),
    prop2 = Subquery(subquery_ref.values('property2ForZscore')),
    prop3 = Subquery(subquery_ref.values('property3ForZscore'))
).select_related('child')
```

And then in your `ChildBmiCheck.zscore`

```
@property
def zscore(self):
    if self.child_was_present:
        return self.calculate_z_score(self.age, self.child.gender, self.prop1, self.prop2, self.prop3)
    # You probably don't need another method to calculate zscore
    # Just write the calculation steps here.
```

Please note I use `Func(field_name, function='AGE')` when annotating age. This only works when your database has AGE function. PostgreSQL has it built in while SQLite3 does not. You will need to write a custom age function yourself then.

**Method 2. Materialized View**

Materialized View is a database functionality that stores a query result into a temporary table, so that on next query, it pull the data directly, without the heavy calculation.

Again, SQLite3 does not support it. Sorry.

Syntax of creating materialized view varies by database. Take PostgreSQL as example.

```
 -- 1. Create a function to calculate zscore
 CREATE FUNCTION zscore(age numeric, gender text, prop1 numeric, prop2  numeric, prop3 numeric) RETURNS numeric AS $$
     -- zscore calculation steps
 $$ LANGUAGE SQL;

 -- 2. Create materialized view
 CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW myapp_childbmicheck_zscore_matview AS
 SELECT b.*, zscore(floor(extract(epoch from date_trunc('month', age(c.date_of_birth))) / 3600 / 24 / 30, c.gender, r.property1ForZscore, r.property2ForZscore, r.property3ForZscore) as zscore
 FROM myapp_childbmicheck b
 LEFT JOIN myapp_child c ON c.id = b.child_id
 LEFT JOIN myapp_referencezscore r ON r.sex = c.gender AND r.age = floor(extract(epoch from date_trunc('month', age(c.date_of_birth))) / 3600 / 24 / 30)
 WITH DATA;
```

Then in you myapp/models.py, create corresponding Model

```
class ChildBmiCheckZscore(models.Model):
    child = models.ForeignKey(Child, models.DO_NOTHING)
    height_in_meters = models.DecimalField(max_digits=40, decimal_places=10, null=True)
    weight_in_kgs = models.DecimalField(max_digits=40, decimal_places=10, null=True)
    child_was_present = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    zscore = models.DecimalField(max_digits=40, decimal_places=10, null=True)
    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'myapp_childbmicheck_zscore_mat_view'
```

Then in your views

```
 queryset = ChildBmiCheckZscore.objects.all()
```

Please note you will need to refresh the materialized view manually, like

```
REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW myapp_childbmicheck_zscore_matview;
```

You need to do this **NOT** annually, but at least monthly, even daily. One child's zscore may change once a year, but you have multiple children with birthdays on different months.

**Method 3. Add A Zscore Field To ChildBmiCheck**

This one is quite straight forward. Calculate zscore each time a `ChildBmiCheck` instance is created.

Comment: Thanks for the amazing answer! I am going to try method 1. I have never seen OuterRef before, but that is the perfect way to pull that filter into annotate!

For completeness, for method 3, where would you calculate the Z score? In a serializer's create/update methods? In the model's save method?

Comment: Also, thanks for the warning about the age! I have a date field that I removed before posting to SO, but you are right, I need to calculate age_at_time and use that in my formula instead!

Comment: I would choose the serializer's create/update methods if I was you, but there is nothing wrong choosing the model's save method.